# Is it possible to announce several IP addresses for a single lightning node according to Lightning protocol specs?

Tags: lightning-rfc

Is it possible to announce several IP addresses for a single lightning node?

The idea is to run a node that is connected to different ISPs to increase its uptime. LND seems to able to run in a cluster using etcd as its database backend. So a multi-homed front-end seems to be the next logical step.